# add action only if gallery shortcode attribute is equal to?

Tags: shortcode, gallery, block-editor

I'm customizing the gallery shortcode. Now, when the user clicks on edit button as shown below:

[image]

We can see the gallery modal like below:

[image]

In the right sidebar, we can see the gallery settings. And I want to remove that settings. So, I am able to remove that. But the problem is that the settings would be removed everywhere.

What I want is if the shortcode attribute has some value then only remove the settings. For eg.:

```
[gallery myattr="true" ids="1,2,3"]
[gallery ids="5,7,9"]
```

Here, we have two gallery shortcodes written using code editor. After switching to the visual editor we can see the image like first in this post. When edit button is clicked for first gallery, it should remove the settings (because it has `myattr="true"`) but when edit button is clicked for second gallery, it should not remove the settings (because it has no  `myattr`).

Is this possible?

```
if(some_condition) {
  // remove the settings
}
```

Where, some_condition probably be using `apply_filters('post_gallery',..`, etc. If there's anyway, I would be thankful to you.